# Merge columns from multiple multidimensional arrays to generate a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose, flatten

Here is my arrays after array chunk by 2

```
$a = [["testA1", "testA2"], ["testA3", "testA4"]];
$b = [["testB1", "testB2"], ["testB3", "testB4"]];
$c = [["testC1", "testC2"], ["testC3", "testC4"]];
```

I want to merge these arrays in below format.

```
$result = array(
    "testA1",
    "testA2",
    "testB1",
    "testB2",
    "testC1",
    "testC2",
    "testA3",
    "testA4",
    "testB3",
    "testB4",
    "testC3",
    "testC4"
);
```

Is there any in-built function available or how to solve this?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_merge` twice with `...` syntax:

```
print_r(array_merge(...array_merge($a, $b, $c)));

// 2nd version
$parts = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    $parts[$k] = array_merge($a[$k], $b[$k], $c[$k]);
}
print_r(array_merge(...$parts));

// hard to understand version:
$parts = array_map(null, $a, $b, $c);
print_r(array_merge(...array_merge(...$parts)));
```

Comment: No. Getting array("testA1","testA2","testA3","testA4", "testB1", "testB2", 
"testB3", "testB4", "testC1", "testC2", "testC3", "testC4"
); But expected result different.  array("testA1","testA2","testB1","testB2", "testC1", "testC2", 
"testA3", "testA4", "testB3", "testB4", "testC3", "testC4"
);

Comment: I think in such case it is more clear to write a `foreach` code, __updated__. Of course `foreach` part can be somehow replaced with another sophisticated `array_` functions, but readability first.

Answer (score 0):

While I personally prefer u_mulder's "transpose-flatten-flatten" technique, this task can be done with fewer cycles.  In fact, you can spread columns of data while pushing elements into the result array in a single loop.  This generates the desired transposed, flat array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rbtTg))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    array_push($result, ...$a[$k], ...$b[$k], ...$c[$k]);
}
var_export($result);
```

---

For the record, u_mulder's transpose-flatten-flatten approach can be one line like this:

```
var_export(
    array_merge(...array_merge(...array_map(null, $a, $b, $c)))
);
```